# Does Lotus Domino 9.0.x still support REQUEST_CONTENT_nnn fields?

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript

In my form design element, say "form1", for some reason, I need to disable its original form behavior and implement another form. So I used `</form>` at the beginning of the "form1" marked with pass-thru. And then I put some pass-thru http lines like below under `</form>`:

```
<form name="simple" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="test?openagent">
<label for="username">Your Name</label>
<input type="text" name="username" /><br />
<label for="email">Your Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email" /><br />
<label for="fileuploader">attachment</label>
<input type="file" name="fileuploader" />
<input type="submit" value="Sign Up!" />
</form>
```

The codes in agent "test" were mainly as below:

```
Dim s As New NotesSession
Dim doc As NotesDocument

Set doc = s.Documentcontext
If doc.Hasitem("REQUEST_CONTENT") Then
    MsgBox "REQUEST_CONTENT=" & doc.REQUEST_CONTENT(0)
Else
    If doc.Hasitem("REQUEST_CONTENT_000") Then
        MsgBox "REQUEST_CONTENT_000=" & doc.REQUEST_CONTENT_000(0)
    End If
End If
ForAll i In doc.Items
    MsgBox i.name & "=" & i.values(0)
End ForAll
```

After I filled the username, email, and picked an attachment, and then submitted the form, I found there was neither "REQUEST_CONTENT" nor "REQUEST_CONTENT_000" item shown; but there was CONTENT_LENGTH item shown and of value 130520.

My question is, in Domino 9.0.x, what item(s) contain(s) the post data?

Answer (score 0):

None. Simple but sad:

1. Notes just allows natively via Notes inserted File Upload Controls.
2. Lotusscript has never been able to handle POSTed binaries.

You should use a Form to accomplish that.